# Asus Pro instead of Asus Pro Live

Tags: openni-launch, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am using the openni_camera module together with the openni_launch on ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte.

when i run openni_launch, it detects the device, but sadly not correct. It detects my Xtion pro live (with RGB) as a Pro, meaning no RGB is provided.

Can anyone direct me as to how to find what's wrong?
Can installing a new driver from the OpenNI website change anything?

Thanks a lot, i hope someone can somehow help me.

**EDIT**

Just to help other people who search for this issue :) The error that i get, when i set depth registration to on using dynamic_reconfigure is

> Device does not provide image + depth
> stream

I also get this after running openni_launch (I never used any other camera on this system):

> [ERROR] [1344530831.835241577]: Tried
> to advertise a service that is already
> advertised in this node
> [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
> [ERROR] [1344530831.841281104]: Tried
> to advertise a service that is already
> advertised in this node
> [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40999/asus-pro-instead-of-asus-pro-live/) by [r.web](https://answers.ros.org/users/3005/r.web/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-08-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue happened for me after I installed the unstable binaries for 12.04 [here](http://openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx).  So I went back and installed the stable Ubuntu 10.10 version of the OpenNI Compliant Hardware Binaries.  Now openni_camera finds my device as "unknown", but I am able to get both depth and RGB (and depth registration using dynamic reconfigure).  So far it is working fine.

---

Originally posted by [rleish](https://answers.ros.org/users/2056/rleish/) with karma: 26 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1